# How to do you restart a container/deployment that is using a PVC?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pvc, persistent-volume-claims

I use `kubectl rollout restart deployment mydeployment-container` as an ad-hoc way to spin up a new container without starting a whole pod over again.

Another behavior I like about this command is that it brings up the new container and gracefully switches once the readiness probe passes before terminating the old container.

Except when using Persistent Volumes Claims:

When I try to to use the same command my new container stays in ContainerCreating with a `Multi-Attach error` It seems as though the persistent volume claim is effectively blocking the creation of a new container, destined to use said persistent volume claim!

Yes, they are configured for `ReadWriteOnce` for internal policy reasons, but no, I can't change that.

I come here because I'm hoping learn a new workflow that will come close to the one I currently use.

Comment: If you are using `ReadWriteOnce` you can't attach the volume on the new container simultaneously. Have you considered to change the volume type or the deploy strategy?

Answer (score 2):

What is your `strategy`, id you replace `RollingUpdate` with `Recreate`, kubernetes will destroy the original pod before starting the successor, thus detaching the volume before it is mounted again.

```
strategy:
    type: Recreate
```